# How to find the largest value that is found within a Maps key

Tags: scala

I have a map of type Map[String, String] with keys like:

```
"dealership_id_1"
"dealership_id_3"
"dealership_id_7"
"dealership_id_39"
```

How can I get the largest value of the ID from the keys? i.e. in this case it is 39

Would it be difficult to extract the id values into a list?
List(1, 3, 7, 39)

My map has maybe 100 keys so it should be a performance issue I would imagine.

Comment: How do those keys have in common?  a prefix of `dealership_id_" or something else?

Answer (score 4):

```
map.keys.map(_.stripPrefix("dealership_id_").toInt).max // 39
```

100 entries is not very many

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex:

```
val id = """_(\d+)""".r
val ids = map.keys.collect { case id(x) => x }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the @Alvaro Carrasco solution but `map.keys.map()` actually creates new collection. I would rather stick to `Iterator` which does not do that:

```
def maxKeySuffix[T](map: Map[String, T]): Int = 
      map.keys.iterator.map(_.stripPrefix("dealership_id_").toInt).max
```